# sub-path in svg imported from a svg file is bigger than expected

Tags: angularjs, svg, snap.svg

I'm working on a clone of 2 precedent website in AngularJs (v1.5.5) + Snap Svg ( v0.5.1 )

in this new one i'm drawing a big stage in which i put a subgroup and fill it with the content of an external svg file imported.

the main code is :

```
scope.addDimPlus = function (item, position, side) {
            Snap.load('img/basi/' + item.svg, function ( fragment ) {

                side = side || 'dx';
                var g = scope.gDimPlus.g();
                g.attr({'type' : 'dim-plus-group'});
                var other = fragment.selectAll('path, rect, line, text');
                for (var i=0; i<other.length; i++) {
                    g.append(other[i]);
                }
                var text = fragment.select('text');
                var path = g.select('path');
                g.addClass('dim-plus-group');
                path.attr({type : 'dim-plus'});
                g.append(text);
                position = position || 0;
                g.attr('id', g.id);
                g.transform('transform(' + position + ')');
            });
        };
```

where item.svg is the filename to load.

In the worknig one the code of the "generated" main stage is this: (taken by Chrome console)

```
    <svg id="svgChain" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 2233 456"> 
<defs>
</defs>
<rect></rect> <--  and other <rect> and <g>
<g id="chain-group" transform="matrix(1.4802,0,0,1.4802,822.7841,72.7528)">
  <g> <-- other 5 <g>
  <g id="verticalSepParetiGroup" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,22.68,31.18)">
   <g id="gSk5xpgcgh4i" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-12.755)" >
    <path d="M42.7,157.5
        c-2.1,0-4.2,0-6.4,0c-2.7,0-5.2-0.1-7.5-1.9c-2.5-2-3.2-4.9-3.2-8c0-5.7,0-11.4,0-17.1c0-9.9,0-19.9,0-29.8c0-11.2,0-22.4,0-33.6
        c0-9.5,0-18.9,0-28.4c0-4.7,0-9.4,0-14.1c0-5,3.8-8.8,8.8-8.8c2.3,0,4.7,0,7,0c1,0,2,0,3-0.3c1.7-0.6,3.1-2,3.6-3.8
        c0.6-1.9,0.2-4.4,0.2-6.4c0-1.3,0-2.6,0-3.9c0-0.2,0.1-1.2,0-1.3c-0.3-0.2-1.9,0-2.2,0c-1.7,0-3.4,0-5.1,0c-10.5,0-20.9,0-31.4,0
        c-2,0-4,0-6,0c-1,0-2.2-0.2-3.2,0c-0.2,0-0.2,0-0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,0,0.7,0,0.8c0,0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7c0,2.4,0,4.7,0,7.1
        c0,3.2,2.4,5.9,5.7,5.9c4.7,0,8.4,3.9,8.5,8.5c0,0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1c0,2.6,0,5.2,0,7.7c0,4.6,0,9.1,0,13.7c0,5.9,0,11.8,0,17.6
        c0,6.6,0,13.2,0,19.7c0,6.7,0,13.3,0,20c0,6.1,0,12.3,0,18.4c0,4.9,0,9.9,0,14.8c0,3.1,0,6.2,0,9.4c0,3.1-0.1,6-2.5,8.3
        c-1.6,1.6-3.8,2.5-6,2.5c-2.5,0-4.8,1.7-5.5,4.2c-0.3,1.1-0.2,2.4-0.2,3.6c0,1.8,0,3.6,0,5.4c0,0.3-0.2,2.2,0,2.4
        c0.1,0.1,0.9,0,1.1,0c0.8,0,1.7,0,2.5,0c2.8,0,5.5,0,8.3,0c7.3,0,14.5,0,21.8,0c3,0,6.1,0,9.1,0c1.1,0,2.1,0,3.2,0
        c0.6,0,1.3,0.1,1.8,0c0.4-0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3-0.5c0-1.6,0-3.1,0-4.7c0-3.2,0.6-7.1-2.2-9.3C45.1,157.9,43.9,157.5,42.7,157.5z"></path>
</g>
</g>
```

and in the NON working project:

```
<svg id="svgChain" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 859 429.5">
<g id="base-group" transform="matrix(1.8364,0,0,1.8364,183.3183,131.4606)">
  <g id="dimaplus" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,4.1)">
    <g type="dim-plus-group" id="gSk5xprcz5f" class="dim-plus-group" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><path d="M94.13 143.83V33.39M113.46 33.94v-.55M118.99 33.94h-5.53M118.99 33.94v109.34M113.46 143.28h5.53M113.46 143.83v-.55M52.61 171.44h30.48M2.06 92.15l35.79 70.25M83.09 5.77H41.67M.25 47.19v37.44M37.85 162.4l1.17 1.95m0 0l1.43 1.77m0 0l1.65 1.56m0 0l1.86 1.32m0 0l2.01 1.05m0 0l2.15.77m0 0l2.22.47m0 0l2.27.15M88.61 171.44v-27.61M88.06 143.83h.55M88.61 171.44v4.97M83.64 176.97h4.42M88.06 143.83h-4.42M83.09 5.77v27.62M.25 84.63l.12 1.95m0 0l.34 1.92m0 0l.57 1.87m0 0l.78 1.78M83.09 5.77V.8M83.09 143.83v27.61M83.09 143.83h.55M41.67 5.77l-4.06.2m0 0l-4.02.6m0 0l-3.94.99m0 0l-3.83 1.37m0 0l-3.67 1.73m0 0l-3.49 2.09m0 0l-3.26 2.42m0 0l-3.01 2.73m0 0l-2.73 3.02m0 0l-2.42 3.26m0 0l-2.09 3.49m0 0l-1.74 3.67m0 0l-1.37 3.83m0 0l-.99 3.94m0 0l-.6 4.02m0 0l-.2 4.06M83.09 176.41v-4.97M88.06.25h-4.42M83.64 33.39h-.55M83.64 33.39h4.42M88.61 176.41l-.16.39m0 0l-.39.17M88.61 33.39V5.77M88.61 33.39h-.55M88.61.8v4.97M83.09.8l.07-.27m0 0l.21-.2m0 0l.27-.08M88.61 143.83h30.38M118.99 169.79H88.61M83.64 176.97l-.39-.17m0 0l-.16-.39M118.99 7.43v25.96M88.06.25l.39.16m0 0l.16.39M118.99 33.39H88.61M88.61 7.43h30.38M118.99 5.77H88.61M118.99 7.43V5.77M118.99 171.44v-1.65M118.99 143.83v25.96M88.61 171.44h30.38M99.38 158.74l.2-1.3m0 0l.57-1.19m0 0l.89-.96m0 0l1.14-.66m0 0l1.29-.29m0 0l1.31.09m0 0l1.23.49m0 0l1.03.82m0 0l.74 1.09m0 0l.39 1.25m0 0v1.32m0 0l-.39 1.26m0 0l-.74 1.09m0 0l-1.03.82m0 0l-1.23.48m0 0l-1.31.1m0 0l-1.29-.3m0 0l-1.14-.65m0 0l-.89-.97m0 0l-.57-1.19m0 0l-.2-1.3M99.38 18.48l.2-1.31m0 0l.57-1.18m0 0l.89-.97m0 0l1.14-.66m0 0l1.29-.29m0 0l1.31.1m0 0l1.23.48m0 0l1.03.82m0 0l.74 1.09m0 0l.39 1.26m0 0v1.31m0 0l-.39 1.26m0 0l-.74 1.09m0 0l-1.03.82m0 0l-1.23.48m0 0l-1.31.1m0 0l-1.29-.29m0 0l-1.14-.66m0 0l-.89-.97m0 0l-.57-1.18m0 0l-.2-1.3M49.96 130.03l.18-2.03m0 0l.56-1.96m0 0l.91-1.83m0 0l1.23-1.62m0 0l1.5-1.38m0 0l1.74-1.07m0 0l1.9-.74m0 0l2-.37m0 0h2.04m0 0l2 .37m0 0l1.9.74m0 0l1.74 1.07m0 0l1.5 1.38m0 0l1.23 1.62m0 0l.91 1.83m0 0l.56 1.96m0 0l.19 2.03m0 0l-.19 2.03m0 0l-.56 1.96m0 0l-.91 1.82m0 0l-1.23 1.63m0 0l-1.5 1.37m0 0l-1.74 1.07m0 0l-1.9.74m0 0l-2 .37m0 0h-2.04m0 0l-2-.37m0 0l-1.9-.74m0 0l-1.74-1.07m0 0l-1.5-1.37m0 0l-1.23-1.63m0 0l-.91-1.82m0 0l-.56-1.96m0 0l-.18-2.03M38.91 130.03l.2-2.95m0 0l.59-2.89m0 0l.96-2.79m0 0l1.33-2.63m0 0l1.67-2.43m0 0l1.98-2.19m0 0l2.26-1.91m0 0l2.48-1.59m0 0l2.68-1.24m0 0l2.82-.87m0 0l2.91-.49m0 0l2.95-.1m0 0l2.93.29m0 0l2.88.69m0 0l2.75 1.06m0 0l2.59 1.42m0 0l2.37 1.75m0 0l2.12 2.05m0 0l1.83 2.31m0 0l1.51 2.54m0 0l1.15 2.72m0 0l.78 2.85m0 0l.39 2.92m0 0v2.95m0 0l-.39 2.93m0 0l-.78 2.84m0 0l-1.15 2.72m0 0l-1.51 2.54m0 0l-1.83 2.31m0 0l-2.12 2.05m0 0l-2.37 1.75m0 0l-2.59 1.42m0 0l-2.75 1.06m0 0l-2.88.69m0 0l-2.93.29m0 0l-2.95-.1m0 0l-2.91-.49m0 0l-2.82-.87m0 0l-2.68-1.24m0 0l-2.48-1.59m0 0l-2.26-1.91m0 0l-1.98-2.18m0 0l-1.67-2.44m0 0l-1.33-2.63m0 0l-.96-2.79m0 0l-.59-2.89m0 0l-.2-2.94M30.63 47.19l.19-2.03m0 0l.55-1.96m0 0l.91-1.82m0 0l1.23-1.63m0 0l1.51-1.37m0 0l1.73-1.08m0 0l1.9-.73m0 0l2-.38m0 0h2.04m0 0l2 .38m0 0l1.91.73m0 0l1.73 1.08m0 0l1.5 1.37m0 0l1.23 1.63m0 0l.91 1.82m0 0l.56 1.96m0 0l.19 2.03m0 0l-.19 2.03m0 0l-.56 1.96m0 0l-.91 1.83m0 0l-1.23 1.62m0 0L48.33 56m0 0l-1.73 1.08m0 0l-1.91.73m0 0l-2 .38m0 0h-2.04m0 0l-2-.38m0 0l-1.9-.73m0 0L35.02 56m0 0l-1.51-1.37m0 0l-1.23-1.62m0 0l-.91-1.83m0 0l-.55-1.96m0 0l-.19-2.03M11.3 47.19l.2-3.46m0 0l.59-3.42m0 0l.98-3.33m0 0l1.35-3.19m0 0l1.7-3.02m0 0l2.04-2.81m0 0l2.34-2.55m0 0l2.63-2.27m0 0l2.86-1.96m0 0l3.07-1.62m0 0l3.23-1.26m0 0l3.35-.88m0 0l3.43-.49m0 0l3.47-.1m0 0l3.45.3m0 0l3.4.69m0 0l3.3 1.07m0 0l3.16 1.44m0 0l2.97 1.79m0 0l2.74 2.12m0 0l2.49 2.41m0 0l2.19 2.69m0 0l1.88 2.92m0 0l1.53 3.11m0 0l1.16 3.26m0 0l.79 3.38m0 0l.4 3.45m0 0v3.47m0 0l-.4 3.44m0 0l-.79 3.38m0 0l-1.16 3.26m0 0l-1.53 3.12m0 0l-1.88 2.91m0 0l-2.19 2.69m0 0l-2.49 2.42m0 0l-2.74 2.11m0 0l-2.97 1.79m0 0l-3.16 1.44m0 0l-3.3 1.08m0 0l-3.4.68m0 0l-3.45.3m0 0l-3.47-.1m0 0l-3.43-.49m0 0l-3.35-.88m0 0l-3.23-1.26m0 0l-3.07-1.62m0 0l-2.86-1.96m0 0l-2.63-2.27m0 0l-2.34-2.55m0 0l-2.04-2.81m0 0l-1.7-3.02m0 0l-1.35-3.19m0 0l-.98-3.33m0 0l-.59-3.42m0 0l-.2-3.46" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".5" type="dim-plus"></path>
```

In the first one I've a path that is INSIDE the "chain-group" group, instead in the other project the path is bigger that the main group (base-group)

does anyone help me to find what i'm missing??? thanks!!!

Comment: If your problem is the fact that part of the path is outside the svg canvas you may need a different value for the viewBox attribute of the svg element

Comment: Your groups have transforms.  Are you allowing for that when you import the external SVG. The external SVG will need to have been designed to take into account that it will get transformed when imported.  

I would recommend that you redesign your main stage SVG(s) so that they don't have any transforms.